# Which job offer is better?

Tags: mortgage, job-offer

I have two jobs offers and I am struggling to assess which one is more advantageous financially.

Offer (1):

- City: NYC;
- Salary: 170k salary base + 30k management bonus;
- Housing benefit: If I buy a place within one year of my start date, the company will loan me without interests 50% of my mortgage up to 425k to help me pay my monthly mortgage payments for the bank. Down payment is still my full responsibility. The mortgage loan can only be done by a selection of two banks that partnered up with the company. If I sell or leave the company within four years, I have to pay principal reduction + interests paid by the company; if I sell or leave after four years, I have to pay only principal reduction paid by the company. In any case, they also will get 50% of the appreciation of the real estate. Furthermore, the remaining of monthly mortgage is take out of my paycheck.
- Example: If I buy a property by $750,000. I need to give at least a 10% down-payment of 75,000. Then, I have to loan $675,000 from a bank. With an interest rate of 7%, my monthly mortgage payment is $4990,00. The company will loan me $375,000, consequently, they will pay 55% of my monthly mortgage payment (0.55 = 375,000/675,000), in other words, my mortgage payment will be $2235,00 (= 4990*0.45). After 5 years, the principal reduction is $43,146.62 and interests paid are $251,249.74. If I leave, I will have to pay the company $21,573.31 (50% of principal reduction) but not $125,624.87 (50% of interest paid).

Offer (2):

- City: Los Angeles
- Salary: 185k
- Housing Benefit: I do not have a deadline to buy a place. The company will loan me 150k split over 10 years, in other words, $15,000 a year or $1250,00 per month. Down payment is still my full responsibility. The mortgage loan can be done in my preferred bank. After 10 years, the loan is forgiven. The countdown of 10 years only starts once I close on a property. If I leave before 10 years, the proportion of time I stayed is forgiven.
- Example: If I buy a property by $750,000. I need to give at least a 10% down-payment of 75,000. Then, I have to loan $675,000 from a bank. With an interest rate of 7%, my monthly mortgage payment is $4990,00, consequently, my mortgage payment will be $3740,00 (= 4990 - 1250). After 5 years, the principal reduction is $43,146.62 and interests paid are $251,249.74. If I leave, I do not have to pay anything, and I would have saved $75,000.

Offer (1) seems better than offer (2) to me, but several colleagues are a bit worried that I would have to pay the company back when I sell or leave the company. I have read ton of articles saying that NYC and LA are comparable in cost of living, except for housing. If I live in LA, I would rather live close to work; In NYC, I could not afford live close to work. Both jobs would require me to be in the office 2-3 times a week.  Also, I do have preferences regarding where I want to live, but I would like to make a thought exercise that makes this decision based only on the financial aspect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Define "better". What's your ultimate goal? There are so many factors, which are not only financial, but even if only considering finances there could be many different scenarios.

Comment: Would more profitable be a reasonable definition of better? I guess my ultimate goal is to build wealth. Which scenarios should I additionally consider?

Comment: commute, food, travel to visit family, etc... If your family is in LA, you'll save on food by eating at your parents' every weekend, while from NYC you'll have to fly back a couple of times a year... Things like that. Anyway, IMHO this is all very subjective

Comment: Open up your trusty spreadsheet and run the numbers, side by side.  What happens if you leave after one year, two years, three years, etc etc?

Answer (score 4):

To me you have not really investigated which offer is better as you left out three key things:  health insurance, vacation, and 401K match benefits.

As far as these two housing offers go, I would reject the NYC housing offer even if I took the job.  There is no way I would let my employer partner with me on the purchase of a home.  The getting 50% of the appreciation would kill it for me.  They may not be providing 50% of the mortgage (if you buy over 850K) and the stipulations makes this a bad business deal.

The second housing offer is bad as well.  Are you really going to stay at an employer for 10+ years?  For the past 20 years or so the best way to bump your salary is to move across the street.    You could easily miss out on far more than the 75K, but maybe not.

I've never heard of such a benefit previously, what industry is the job in?

So for me, it would come down to vacation and 401K match.  I would tend to want to be in LA, but a case can be made for NYC.  If you are a heterosexual male in NYC you can do very well with the ladies as competition would be low.

For the record, years ago, I rejected a 170K/year offer in NYC for a 110K offer in Florida due to the fact that the Florida offer was far more lucrative when you figured in cost of living.

Comment: Are the jobs equal in how much they expect you to work? Some places tout work-life balance but have people averaging 50-60 hours/week, others you can manage under 40. Consider advancement opportunities at both jobs and/or which might sound more impressive to future employers.